# XML schema - "Element not supported in this context"

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm having a problem with my last content in my code. It says that:

> "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" is not supported in this context.

How do I solve this?

Screenshot of the problem:

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"   
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Ansökan">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="hejsanförskolan">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>   
              <xs:element maxOccurs="2" name="vårdnadstagare">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="personnummer" type="datatypPersonnummer"minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="förnamn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="efternamn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="Adress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                    <xs:element name="Telefonnummer" type="xs:unsignedInt" minOccurs="1" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>                 
              <xs:element name="ömmandeskäl">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="allergi" type="xs:string" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:simpleType name="datatypPersonnummer">
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{10}"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the other inline type (for element `vårdnadstagare`): you have the sequence containing an element which contains the type.

But in the case with the error you've put the simple type *direct* in the sequence.

You need an element there.

Eg.

```
<xs:sequence>
  …
  <xs:element name="datatypPersonnummer">
     <xs:simpleType>
       <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{10}"/>
       </xs:restriction>
     </xs:simpleType>
   </xs:element>
```

Ie. wrap existing `<xs:simpleType name="datatypPersonnummer">` in a new `<xs:element>`, moving the `name` attribute on to the new element.

Comment: Im extremly new within XML how'd i do that :) ?

Comment: @supbro Just like the other elements are defined in that XSD.

Comment: Could you show what you mean becouse i have no idea :/

Comment: @supbro OK, added the relevant bit, but [SO] is neither a tutorial or code writing service: you are expected to know the basics (in this case XML syntax and the basics of XSD).

Answer (score 0):

Type datatypPersonnummer is in the wrong location. This works:

```
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:simpleType name="datatypPersonnummer">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{10}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```