# XSD correction on XML?

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

i have the data in my `xml` shown as:

```
<xs:element name="location">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element type="xs:string" name="coords"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I would like to the schema to fix the location from having a height

```
<location>
 <coords>
   13.45,12.25,2.33
 </coords>
</location>
```

to simply be 13.45,12.25 (height ommitted)

can this be forced by the XSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use a regular expression to enforce the check. Should be something along the following lines:

```
<xs:element name="location">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:element type="no-height-coords" name="coords"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:simpleType name="no-height-coords">
 <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
  <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+\.[0-9]+,[0-9]+\.[0-9]+"/>
 </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: I keep getting a warning ..."..XMLSchema:simpleType element is not supported in this context"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919382/xml-schema-element-not-supported-in-this-context ok!